# change wordpress navigation item menu background color on active

Tags: html, css

hello i am trying to change the background color of my menu item when ever a page is active or selected, i tried it the normal way using css, this what i have tried

```
#tve_editor .thrv_widget_menu.thrv_wrapper ul.tve_w_menu a:selected {
    color: #373737;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
#tve_editor .thrv_widget_menu.thrv_wrapper ul.tve_w_menu a:active {
    color: #373737;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}

#tve_editor .thrv_widget_menu.thrv_wrapper ul.tve_w_menu a:current {
    color: #373737;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

This is what i am trying to achieve

[image]

This is the present page you can see the state of the menu:
[web link](http://musiccareerblueprint.com/mine/)

Is there any other way i can get this menu to look that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#tve_editor .thrv_widget_menu.thrv_wrapper ul.tve_w_menu li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: #373737;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: can u imagine it ws thr right along, i kept on looking for selectors

Answer (score 1):

You need to use hover css selector.Take a look here!
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_link_more1

something like:

```css
#tve_editor .thrv_widget_menu.thrv_wrapper ul.tve_w_menu a:hover {
    color: #373737;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer. The question was "... change the background color of my menu item when ever a page is active or selected"

Comment: its nt an on hover effect i want, its to assign a bacground colour to the current page menu, thanks for ur response

Comment: If thats he could try change the backround color to yellow or whatever  he wants to with only tweaking a:active and a:selected